# Python filtering in a list of lists by partial string

Tags: python, list

Newbie question here...

I have a list of lists and I need to filter out entire elements (rows) if one occurrence of a partial string in a row exists.

E.g.

```
df = [['frog','womble','badger'], ['frog','ant','owl'], ['frog','badger','dataERRORdata']]
```

I need to search on `%ERROR%` (because the surrounding text is large and changeable) and for that to remove the entire element, leaving;

```
[['frog','womble','badger'], ['frog','ant','owl']]
```

I've tried a few list comprehensive/generator type loops but can't get it work. Would be quite useful to have an example just based on the above so I can tweak it to the specific case I have.

Feels like this is simple and I'm just missing something easy

Thanks!

Comment: check the `in` operator

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator expression within `all` to check each sublist for a string containing `'ERROR'`, the use a list comprehension to loop over those sublists to filter.

```
>>> [sub for sub in df if all('ERROR' not in s for s in sub)]
[['frog', 'womble', 'badger'], ['frog', 'ant', 'owl']]
```

Answer (score 3):

This comprehension with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will do:

```
df = [['frog','womble','badger'],['frog','ant','owl'],['frog','badger','dataERRORdata']]

clean = [sub for sub in df if not any('ERROR' in w for w in sub)]
# [['frog', 'womble', 'badger'], ['frog', 'ant', 'owl']]
```

This is short-hand for the following nested loop ([docs on for-else](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)):

```
clean = []
for sub in df:
    for w in sub:
        if 'ERROR' in w:
            break
    else:  # loop not broken out of
        clean.append(sub)
```